# Why does android studio crash the app before launch?

Tags: java, android

Just started learning Android Studio. Faced a problem: my application crashes before launch. I don't understand what is the reason for this. Please tell me.

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
        tools:targetApi="31" >
        <activity
            android:name=".login"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

> MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

public class MainActivity {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    }
}
```

[image]

> UPD: Error msg

[image]

Comment: Share the crash message also.

Comment: Please post the error/crash message.

Comment: already posted it

Comment: do not post images of text

Answer (score 2):

Remove this from the `<application>` declaration in the manifest:

```
android:name=".MainActivity"
```

You only need to specify the `android:name` if you are providing a custom implementation of the `Application` class. The error you are getting says that it is failing trying to cast an instance of `MainActivity` to `Application` because `MainActivity` isn't a subclass of `Application`.

Comment: removed but didn't help

Comment: I assume you have a different error now. Please edit the question and post the new error message/stack trace.